# exit on pressing back if on main page of app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating a game. I have one "quit" button on first page and another button "select weapon" on second page I have a "back" button which through Intent moves back to first page but pressing device's back button or "quit" again, I got redirected to the weapon page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `startActivity(Intent intent)` to go from the second page back to the first page. Just call `finish()` instead.